# Excel - Array formula with gap

Tags: arrays, excel, array-formulas

Currently I have this formula working fine as an array formula, to determine the maximum from the differences between values of 2 arrays:

```
{=MAX(ABS(D3:N3-AW3:BG3))}
```

I am trying to exclude one pair of values from the middle of both arrays (cells `L3` and `BE3` respectively). This does not work:

```
{=MAX(ABS(D3:K3;M3:N3-AW3:BD3;BF3:BG3))}
```

I am getting the "too many arguments"error; the error does make sense from the `ABS` function's perspective - as the semicolon is argument separator. But how can one work with gaps in the arrays (i.e. - non-adjacent cells) ?

Comment: you can use `(D3:K3;M3:N3)` but the formula will probably use only the first area `D3:K3` or result in error, so you will need separate Max functions for the separate areas

Comment: @Slai it does result in an error, and the 2 MAX functions is a nice workaround; but what is the correct syntax for "gapped" arrays ?

Comment: not sure what you mean, `()` is the only way I know. Maybe something like this might work `{=MAX(ABS(D3:K3-AW3:BD3);ABS(M3:N3-BF3:BG3))}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using ';' you can use ':'. The below formula would work for you.

```
{=MAX(ABS(D3:K3-AW3:BD3), ABS(M3:N3-BF3:BG3))}
```

Comment: using your suggested formula, the `L3-BE3` difference still gets returned as `MAX` (when it is the largest)

Comment: ...although, if I double click the formula, it shows the correct ranges highlighted

Comment: I edited the formula. Splitting is range is the otherway =MAX(ABS(D3:K3-AW3:BD3), ABS(M3:N3-BF3:BG3))

Answer (score 1):

**Array formula****

`=MAX(ABS(D3:K3-AW3:BD3);ABS(M3:N3-BF3:BG3))`

Regards